LDAP_Search giving an empty array
I'm a LDAP newbie and I'm trying to get a PHP webapp to talk to my company's Active Directory server.
I have the following code:
$ldap_server = 'ldap://server.domain.local';
$ldap_domain = '@domain.local';
$ldapport = 389;                                                
$ldap_admin_user = "admin_user";
$ldap_admin_password = 'admin_password';
try {
    $ldapconn = ldap_connect($ldap_server);
    
    ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
    ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
            
    $bind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldap_admin_user.$ldap_domain, $ldap_admin_password);
    if ($bind) {
            $arr = array('cn', 'sAMAccountName');
            $ldapsearch = (object)[];
            $ldapsearch = ldap_search(
                $ldapconn, 
                'OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=local', 
                "(objectClass=person)",
                $arr
            ) or die ("Error trying to bind: ".ldap_error($ldapconn));
            
            var_dump ($ldapsearch); 
            
            //$entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $ldapsearch);
            
    }
    else {
        echo "SyncError: LDAP bind failed"
    }

} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo "SyncError: LDAP connection failed"
}

I get the following result:
object(LDAP\Result)#24 (0) { } 

However, if I use an LDAP explorer (JXplorer) on the same machine using the same credentials, protocol, and exact same filter string, then I can see the hierarchy of results. I have no idea why PHP is not grabbing the entries. I am on PHP 8.3.9 if that helps. This is also on a Windows machine.
I have tried changing up the filter string. Tried binding using a different admin user. Explicitly declaring the port in the ldap_connect. No change.
Would it also matter if I have my Users nested under two other OU's?
Eg: my base DN is current OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=Local. But what if I have two more OUs (OU=Group1 and OU=Group2) within OU=Users and my users are in those 2 groups?

Did you check your error logs?

Are you talking about the php error logs for the site? I've checked them and there's no errors related to the code I'm running. Unless you're talking about some other error log?

I'm not able to test right now, but I suspect that var_dump doesn't work the way you expect on an LDAP\Result object. The example on the ldap_search page shows that you need to call ldap_get_entries on the results, which you already have in your code, but commented out:
$entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $ldapsearch);

At that point, var_dump($entries) might work, but you can also do echo $entries["count"] to get the number of results.

I've tried that. I get the following results:
array(1) { ["count"]=> int(0) }
So I suspect it's more an issue with the ldap_search.

@TrieuNguyen-Tran Have you tried removing the line setting LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS to 0? Maybe it needs to follow a referral, which is the default (although if that was the case I would expect some kind of error).

I have tried removing the referrals. No change.
